# How to add elements into array in Class Object in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to add an element to the array and keep all existing elements in place. Currently whenever I add it's changing the original array only to that added element.

My code below:

```
 public $items = [];
 public function addProduct($singleProduct, $quantity)
    {
        
        $this->items[count($items)] = $singleProduct;
    }
```

Add when I try to dump them it only displays one element even if I add multiple. Functio that return current items in the array:

```
public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }
```

I am adding items in the following way :

```
if (isset($_POST["add"])){

        $productToAdd = $productsFromDB->findProduct($_GET["id"]);
        $newCartItem= $cart->addProduct($productToAdd, $_POST["quantity"]);
        echo $cart->getItems();
```

Comment: Are the items in the cart saved in a session of any kind?

Comment: @Daan I am not storing them in any session. How can I implement that? I have update the code with $this->items

Comment: Why not just `$this->items[] = $item`?

Comment: You can use the global variable `$_SESSION` https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: Add what stage do I change the session to store the elements? Do I need to use sessions at all times even if I am working with Classes? @Daan

Comment: A very basic example would be to create a `$_SESSION['cart']` variable. Everytime you add or remove products, you update the session. And yes, sessions do not replace classes.

Comment: Sessions aren't in any way tied to classes. They serve a purpose of preserving state between multiple requests. You could achieve the same thing with a database, for example.

Comment: Thanks, it starting to make sense. I have posted the code below. Where there  I could edit the session when adding the item? @El_Vanja

Comment: You're in the proces of learning two completely different aspects of programming (OOP and state/sessions). My advice to you is, dive into one of them first instead of trying to understand them both.

Comment: Please don't add new information as an answer, edit your question instead.

Answer (score -1):

You initialize an `$items` empty array, but you never set your `$this->item` with the given `$item` array. You  are losing somthing on the way.

You should iniitialize you Cart first

```php
$cart = new Cart();
$items = $cart->getItems();
```

modify your array assuming that the `addProduct()` function is a Cart method.

```php
$cart->addProduct($product, $quantity);
```

The `addProduct` might return the `$cart` itself or be void

```php
# retuen the object
function addProduct($product, $quantity)
{
    $this->items[] = $product;
    return $this;
}
$cart = $cart->addProduct($prod, $qty);


#return nothing
function addProduct($product, $quantity)
{
    $this->items[] = $product;
    return $this;
}
$cart->addProduct($prod, $qty);
```

Maybe you could have more benefits using the productId as array key of the give product, assuming that you have a id getter for you Product ojb.
something like that:

```php
 public function addProduct($singleProduct, $quantity)
    {
        $productId = $singleProduct->getId();
        $this->items[productId] = $singleProduct;
    }
```

You can get a prodcut in a better way, and you can saolve the problem of the array key